# Store value in variable using stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in Redshift which count number of names in one table and store this count in another table adding the datetime and de number of registers from the count.

For example my source table is this:

| name | surname | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| will | smith | 1234 |
| will | smith | 1234 |
| matthew | perry | 5678 |

Desired output in a new table:

| name | surname | phone | count | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| will | smith | 1234 | 2 | 2023-11-02 12:39:41.181 +0100 |

My code to create this procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_procedimientos.insertar_registro (name VARCHAR(255), surname VARCHAR(255), phone VARCHAR(20))
AS $$
DECLARE
    total_registros bigint;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO total_registros COUNT(name) FROM test_procedimientos.registro;
    INSERT INTO test_procedimientos.registro_inserciones1(total_registros, name, surname, phone, date)
    VALUES (total_registros, name, surname, phone, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have tried change my select with `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total_registros FROM test_procedimientos.registro;`

but I get the following error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" Where: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "insertar_registro" near line 6

I have tried with other procedures such this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_procedimientos.test_sp1(f1 int, f2 varchar(20))
AS $$
DECLARE
  min_val int;
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tbl;
  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_tbl(id int);
  INSERT INTO tmp_tbl values (f1),(10001),(10002);
  SELECT INTO min_val MIN(id) FROM tmp_tbl;
  RAISE INFO 'min_val = %, f2 = %', min_val, f2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and this works so I don't understand why my procedure doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using INSERT VALUES syntax, you must insert constants not references to table of query. For example, you don't have defined what is "nombre".

Comment: @EdgarsT. sorry I made a mistake with the names. Edited to show the correct naming

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that "name", "surname", "phone" can't be used in this syntax. In your second (working) example you are doing insert from select, where you can reference columns from table.

Comment: Also - error in line most likely means 6th line starting from $$, so it is insert statement not first select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres [count()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-aggregate.html) function returns a bigint. You're trying to put it into an integer. These are not the same. Your other function works because Min() returns the same type as the input.

edit: then the next part is to simplify your procedure. Comment out the insert. Check the insert works by itself (as I think you want current_date, not date in the query). And so on, you may be thinking the problem is with the select and its really with the insert statement.

Comment: I have changed total_registros to bigint and still doesn`t work...